# Facing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type error in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a small experimental project whose structure is as follows:

```
demo
|----->src/main/java
       |---->com.java.application
       |     |---->DemoApplication.java
       |---->com.java.model
             |---->Customer.java
             |---->CustomerRepository.java
```

Where my DemoApplication.java is

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.java.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses= {CustomerRepository.class})
@EntityScan("com.java.model.Customer")
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {
        // save a couple of customers
        repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Kim", "Bauer"));
        repository.save(new Customer("David", "Palmer"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Michelle", "Dessler"));
    };
    }
}
```

I have added @Entity to my Customer.java class

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

protected Customer() {}

public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(
            "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
            id, firstName, lastName);
}
}
```

And my CustomerRepository.java is as
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>{
List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

But when I run I keep getting errors. I have tried the solutions in other posts for this problem but none are working.

I keep getting: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.java.model.Customer

What is wrong here?

Comment: move your `DemoApplication.java` to `com.java`. As adviced by the Spring Boot team. And remove all your annotations but `@SpringBootApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.java.model"})` to `@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.java.model.*"})`

Answer (score 0):

I have two tips for you.

1. First of all rename your packages structure com.java is a very bad practice. You could have several libraries in your class path which named like that "com.java". You use something like this: "org.mysupertest"
2. Just delete ComponentScan and EntityScan. Use the following construction:

   ```
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "org.mysupertest")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

That error may be come from some issues, like spring boot basepackages or scan packageBases. You should refactor the main class DemoApplication like this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.java.application.*")
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.java.application.*" })
 @EntityScan("com.java.application.model.*")
public class DemoApplication {
   // your code here
}
```

a) The main class is always located in the based package.

b) Other classes should be located in subpackages of the based package.

c) One more, don't name your package is com.java. It is not good.

If you want to know the working example, visit the post [Spring Boot Restful Web Services Example](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-restful-web-services-example.html)